# asp.net mvc views precompiling and merging

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After publishing my asp.net mvc app with precompiling I got many compiled views like _layout.cshtml.639c3968.compiled. However, none of merge options actually merge these views to a single assembly. I tried "Merge all outputs to a single assembly" and "Merge all pages and control outputs to a single assembly" without success. So, is there any built-in working way to merge the views?

Comment: Have you tried using the [ASP.NET Merge Tool (Aspnet_merge.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397866(v=vs.100).aspx) ?

Comment: Visual studio uses it during publishing. I can see it in "web publish activity" window. It doesn't merge compiled razor views.